# Automate to fetch the CLOUDFRONT IP list from https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jq

Is there a way to execute the below command in Python script to automate and get the results as expected below in an s3 bucket:

```
curl https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json |
  jq -r '.prefixes[] | select(.service=="CLOUDFRONT") | "set_real_ip_from \(.ip_prefix);"
  ' > set_real_ip_from.inc
```

Output of the command:

```
set_real_ip_from 34.216.51.0/25;
set_real_ip_from 34.223.12.224/27;
set_real_ip_from 34.223.80.192/26;
set_real_ip_from 34.226.14.0/24;
set_real_ip_from 35.158.136.0/24;
set_real_ip_from 35.162.63.192/26;
set_real_ip_from 35.167.191.128/26;
set_real_ip_from 44.227.178.0/24;
set_real_ip_from 44.234.108.128/25;
set_real_ip_from 44.234.90.252/30;
set_real_ip_from 52.15.127.128/26;
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible make http requests and parse json in python.

Comment: Can you please share if any reference doc to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this if you want to execute it from a python script:

```py
import os
os.system('cmd /k "curl https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json | jq -r \'.prefixes[] | select(.service==\"CLOUDFRONT\") | \"set_real_ip_from \(.ip_prefix);\" \' > set_real_ip_from.inc"')
```